# How to scrape data in h4 with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the results data from this website (https://www.ufc.com/matchup/908/7717/post) and I am completely at a loss for why my proposed solution isn't working.

The outer html that I am trying to scrape is `<h4 class="e-t5 winner">Jon Jones</h4>`. I don't have a lot of experience with web scraping or HTML but all of the relevant information is contained in the `h4` tag.

I have been successful in extracting the data from the `h2` tag but I am confused as to why the same approach doesn't work for `h4`. For example, to extract the relevant data from `<h2 class="field--name-name name_given red">Jon Jones <span class="field--field-rank rank"></span></h2>` the following code works.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',
    }
raw_html = get('https://www.ufc.com/matchup/908/7717/post', headers=headers)
html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html.content)

# this works
html.find_all('h2', attrs={'class': 'field--name-name name_given red'})[0].get_text().strip()

# this does not work?
html.find_all('h4', attrs={'class': 'e-t5 winner red'})

# this code gets me to the headers but not the actual listed data inside
html.find('div', attrs={'class': 'l-flex--4col-2to4'})
```

I am mostly confused as to why the above doesn't work and why the text I can see when inspecting the element in my browser, doesn't appear in the scraped HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is added dynamically. You can find the source in the network tab. Assuming there is always one winner you can use something like

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://dvk92099qvr17.cloudfront.net/V1/908/Fnt.json').json()
winner = [fighter['FullName'] for fighter in r['FMLiveFeed']['Fights'][0]['Fighters'] if fighter['Outcome'] == 'Win'][0]
print(winner)
```

Comment: This has been incredibly helpful! How did you generate that json though? I went to the network tab in my browser but am unable to find any reference to the returned data you posted. I obviously don't have a lot of experience with programming on the web, how did you find the json so easily? Thanks!

Comment: I opened network tab in dev tools F12 > Pressed F5 to refresh page > Press Ctrl + F to open search box and searched for various terms including "Winner", "Win". Saw there were some json responses happened to copy one into https://jsoneditoronline.org/? then searched again for "Winner" and "Win" found the path to the recorded result then went back to search box and search for "Win" with the "".

Comment: That's very helpful. Given the results are dynamically generated like this, is it not possible to scrape with beautiful soup in a programmatic way? Would I need to use something like selenium to scrape this data?

Comment: That might be easier however it looks like the 908 is an id so you may just need https://dvk92099qvr17.cloudfront.net/V1/{id}/Fnt.json  and for future scrapes just add in the id. If you provide another fight I can have a look for you.